# Unit Test Sessions Window Closes when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

When I select an NUnit test in the Unit Test Sessions window and click debug, the window disappears. My breakpoints are hit, but if I hit F5, the Unit Test Sessions window does not return until the test returns a result or I stop the debugging session. This is preventing me from viewing any console output during tests. Any ideas?

Comment: What is activating your unit tests?  What calls them?

Comment: It happens on Right Click -> Run Unit Tests in Solution Explorer as well as when I click the green debug button in the Unit Test Sessions window.

Comment: Which unit test runner are you using?

Comment: Is the console window open during execution?  Are you writing data out to the console?  If not, it won't show up.  Do you mean the watch window so you can see the values in your variables?

Comment: No, I mean the Console. The Unit Test Session window displays anything written via Console.Write() below the unit test runner, but the entire window is hidden

Comment: @Grzenio - your comment helped me solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: You can have different windows open for "Write" mode versus "Debug" mode.  Perhaps the console window is truly hidden for debug mode and it simply means you need to show it?

Comment: Thanks Nick. It was the Output pane in the Resharper Unit Test Sessions window that Console.WriteLine() is writing to when my Unit tests are running under the RS test runner. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turned out to be the Resharper Test Runner that was mis-behaving. The answer was to reopen the window using **ReSharper** -> **Windows** -> **Unit Test Sessions** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> if using the IntelliJ shortcuts.